# Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

Whenever I try to upload a image then it shows me this error

> Warning: `file_get_contents()`: Filename cannot be empty

My code is:

```
<?php
$ImageName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$ImageType = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
$ImageSize = $_FILES["file"]['size'];
$ImgData   = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$sql       = "insert into image(imagename,imagesize,imagetype,imagecontent) values('{$ImageName}','{$ImageSize}','{$ImageType}','{$ImgData}')";
$result    = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` what do you get?

Comment: Are you sure there's a file in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`? Try to dump it like @aynber said

Comment: Your code uses the totally outdated and long deprecated mysql extension that actually does not exist any more in current php versions. You really should upgrade.

Comment: Saving images itself in the database will make it very large, hard to backup and may occupy memory from the MySQL buffer pool. I prefer to save them on disk

Answer (score 1):

Read your error message carefully, all information needed is in there :)

`file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty` means, that the "thing" that you gave the function is "empty" and it should not be "empty". So, what are you inserting into that function?

Correct.
`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` is empty. So somewhere in your other code you have something that's not correct, or something is misspelled.

If you encounter such message, do a log/print of that variable or of the whole array. Then you will see that there is no string in this part of the array.